# Aymptotic formula/closed form for $ \sum_{r=1}^{n} {n \choose r} \frac{f^{(r-1)}(1)}{(r-1)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

For an $f$ infinitely differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and real valued, consider a finite sum $$a_n= \sum_{r=1}^{n} {n \choose r} \frac{f^{(r-1)}(1)}{(r-1)!}$$
where $f^{(r-1)}(1)=\frac{d^{(r-1)}f(x)}{dx^{(r-1)}}|_{x=1} $ and "$!$" denotes the factorial notation.

> **Question:** Find a closed form of $a_n$ similar to the following : $$ \sum_{r=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{r}x^r=(1+x)^n$$

My Attempt: I tried using Binomial formula but could not get the solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134107/discussion-on-question-by-ashlyn-aymptotic-formula-closed-form-for-sum-r1).

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the discussion in the comments,

$$a_n = \sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\frac{f^{(r-1)}(1)}{(r-1)!}$$

Note that:

$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n}{r} \binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

Therefore,

$$a_n = n\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{r-1}\frac{f^{(r-1)}(1)}{r!}$$

$$\implies n!a_n = n\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{r-1}\bigg(\frac{n!}{r!}\bigg)f^{(r-1)}(1)$$

$$= n\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{r-1}\bigg(\frac{d^{(n-r)}}{{dx}^{(n-r)}}x^n\bigg)f^{(r-1)}(x)\Bigg|_{x=1}$$

$$= n\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{r}\bigg(\frac{d^{(n-1-r)}}{{dx}^{(n-1-r)}}x^n\bigg)f^{(r)}(x)\Bigg|_{x=1}$$

$$\implies n!a_n =n\frac{d^{(n-1)}}{{dx}^{(n-1)}}\bigg(x^nf(x)\bigg)\Bigg|_{x=1}$$
by Leibniz rule. Hence:

$$a_n =\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{(n-1)}}{{dx}^{(n-1)}}\bigg(x^nf(x)\bigg)\Bigg|_{x=1}$$